# database design to store user comments and their ratings

Tags: mysql, database

I am fresher in database side. I am developing entertainment site. That site having user comment, reply comment for that user comment and rating for that user comment. For this, how I can design a database to store user comment, reply comment for that user comment and rating for that user comment.

User can post their comment only when login into the site. But this restriction is not apply for rating. User can give a rating without login into the site.

Any help will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: So you want to store Anonymous ratings too

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I am blank. Yes i want to store anonymous rating as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 tables; Comments & Replies

```
table comments:
#Comment_id(int)(pk)
*Users_id(int)(fk)
*Comment_content (varchar(500))
*Comment_rating(int)
*Comment_date(date)

table replies:
#Reply_id(int)(pk)
*Comment_id(int)(fk)
*Users_id(int)(fk)
*Reply_rating(int)
*Reply_content(varchar(500))

pk-> primary key
fk-> foreign key
#-> unique identifier
*->mandatory
```

The table "Users" is the table where your users are stored. Keep note this stores the content of a reply as flat text. I did not take into account the possibility of uploading images.
The rating fields are mandatory because the comments and replies have ratings. The fact that you need to be logged in to comment or reply is enforced because an user id is required. however to enable anonymous users to rate, that should not be done in the database at all. That should be done on the website itself. That would be a button that updates the field of the comment/reply with the corresponding ID.

note; this is not a perfect example. you should do research on database design and normalization. Nevertheless this will get you started.